# Método Compartir de Android no comparte texto e imagen, solo imagen sola

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Tengo un metodo para compartir imagenes por medio de SMS, WhatsApp, Fb, Correo, etc.; que al llamarlo se le pasa una URL.

El metodo descarga la imagen de la URL compartida y queda la imagen lista para compartir (se utiliza `Xamarin.Essentials.Share`).

**El problema es que le paso un titulo junto con la imagen como propiedad parte del metodo, pero el titulo no me lo muestra al momento de compartir, solo la imagen sola, y no me sirve asi ya que la enviaria sin ningun contexto o informacion. Y en este metodo no me sale el parametro `Text`.**

¿Alguna otra idea de como pasar la imagen y un texto?

Metodo de imagen (C# - Xamarin.Android):

```
public async Task DescargaryCompartirImagenEn(string URL)
        {
            try
            {
                string localPath = "";

                var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
                    bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                    string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

                    var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                    string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];
                    localFilename = "MyAPP" + localFilename;
                    localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage

                    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context, new string[] { localPath }, null, null);
                };
                var url = new Uri(URL);
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);

                var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];
                localFilename = "MyAPP" + localFilename;
                string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;
                localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);

                //Descargada.



            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
                {
                    Title = **"Con tecnología de MyAPP"**,
                    File = new ShareFile(localPath)
                });
            }
        }
```

[image: Error]

**Cabe destacar que si utilizo otro metodo de `Share` que es solo para texto, ahi si lo comparte sin problemas.**

Metodo de solo texto:

```
private async Task CompartirEn(string Tipo, string Titulo, string ContenidoaCompartir)
        {
            try
            {
                await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
                {
                    Uri = "Con tecnologia de MyAPP",
                    Title = Titulo, 
                    Subject = (Tipo + " de " + Titulo).ToString(),
                    Text = "MyApp - " + Tipo + " de " + Titulo + ":" + System.Environment.NewLine + ContenidoaCompartir + System.Environment.NewLine
                });
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message; Crashes.TrackError(Ex);
            }
        }
```

**¿Seria posible combinarlos ambos o conocen un método que permita lo que necesito en C#?**

¿WhatsApp, Facebook y Messenger permiten el "pegado" de imágenes. Hay alguna forma de "copiar" la imagen y pegarla junto con el texto? O tal vez al reves: Compartir la imagen (que es lo mas complicado) con el metodo de imagen y llevar el texto en el `portapapeles` para solo pegarlo automaticamente?

Comment: No es un error... ese mensaje no tiene un "Título"... y le estás seteando el título. Si lo compartes por email, por ejemplo, si detecta el `Title`. Suerte consiguiendo que funcione, nunca lo he podido hacer :)

Comment: Gracias por la observacion. Tienes razon. De igual forma me supongo que debe haber una manera, no?

Comment: Editado para una mejor comprension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontré esta respuesta en el sitio en ingles:

> La forma en que envía datos con intent depende de la disponibilidad
> de aplicaciones que filtran su acción particular. Las aplicaciones que
> manejan ACTION_SEND pueden no manejar ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE. Al hacer
> clic en Compartir en la Galería de HTC, se genera una lista de
> aplicaciones que manejan imágenes, únicas o múltiples. Si elige
> Correo, puede seleccionar varias imágenes. Pero si elige Facebook o
> Peep, solo puede seleccionar una imagen. Esta es mi solución simple si
> desea hacer lo contrario de la Galería de HTC, es decir: el usuario
> elige las imágenes primero y luego le muestra todas las aplicaciones
> compatibles según la cantidad que seleccionó.

```
// assuming uris is a list of Uri
Intent intent = null;
if (uris.size > 1){
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
} else if (uris.size() == 1) {
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));}
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some message");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"compatible apps:"));
```

como veras esta implementando `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` lo cual agrega texto adicional.

Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931611/action-send-sending-both-an-image-and-text-in-the-same-intent

Tendrías que adaptar esto a tus necesidades.

También encontré esta otra respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775454/17161735

Esta tambien implementa `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` para compartir el texto, pero convierte la imagen a base64 para utilziarla como string:

> Logré hacerlo de una manera más simple! Creé una base64 a partir de la
> imagen y la agregué como una cadena en el archivo strings.xml
> (asegúrese de eliminar los datos: image / png; base64, desde el inicio
> de la cadena).
>
> El código que utilicé es el siguiente:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(getString(R.string.share_image), Base64.DEFAULT); //The string is named share_image.
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
Uri imageToShare = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), decodedByte, "Share image", null)); //MainActivity.this is the context in my app.
String textToShare = "Sample text"; //Text to be shared

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageToShare);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with"));
```

Comment: Estaba leyendo algo similar, pero aparentemente solo permite: 1. Compartir uri/url o 2. Compartir imagen de los recursos de la app en drawable. -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333186/how-to-share-image-text-together-using-action-send-in-android --

Comment: @KennyAli y que pasa con el `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` ???

Comment: me parece que la APP receptora debe tener el soporte para leer ese campo/parametro ...

Comment: @KennyAli mira esta opción: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25065367/17161735

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas compartir usando la clase `Share` podràs ver que el pàrametro title se muestra en la pantalla antes de compartir,  podras lograr esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al poner el mensaje dependiendo del cliente por ejemplo en el caso de la imagen que presentas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es un SMS ese titulo no se envìa en el mensaje.

Comment: Pero igual, aca no se esta compartiendo el texto. Solo me lo muestra a mi.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que vayas a encontrar un método tal cual lo necesitas para compartir `Imagen + Texto` juntos. Especialmente porque aunque encuentres un método en C#, me parece que Facebook no permite recibir ambos parámetros juntos por Intent.

Lo que puedes intentar hacer es compartir la imagen con tu método y llevar el texto que quieres compartir en el `portapapeles` para solo decirle al usuario antes de salir de tu app que llevara el texto en el portapapeles y que solo tiene que pegarlo antes de enviarlo.

De este modo:

```
public async Task CompartirEn(string URL, string Titulo, string ContenidoaCompartir, string Tipo = "Sinopsis")
        {
            try
            {
                string localPath = "";

                var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
                    bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                    string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

                    var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                    string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];
                    localFilename = "SpoiledBuff" + localFilename;
                    localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                    localPath2 = localPath.ToString();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage

                    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context, new string[] { localPath }, null, null);
                };
                var url = new Uri(URL);
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);

                var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];
                localFilename = "SpoiledBuff" + localFilename;
                string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;
                localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                localPath2 = localPath.ToString();

                //Descargada. Compartir...   
                

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)GetSystemService(Context.ClipboardService);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.NewPlainText(Tipo, ContenidoaCompartir);
                clipboard.PrimaryClip = (clip);

                await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
                {
                    Title = (Tipo + " de " + Titulo).ToString(),
                    File = new ShareFile(localPath2)
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Si, ya habia pensado algo asi. Si no encuentro una mejor idea creo que tendra que ser de ese modo.

Comment: Hola @Jorge.Mendez, **te sugiero revisar acerca de Sock Puppets**:
[¿Por qué me quitaron puntos de reputación?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196)
[¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange)